# Finding number of edges given vertices and degree sequence?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm doing a question in my text that asks me to find how many regions a graph has if it has 6 vertices all of which has degree 4. I know i'm supposed to use the euler theorem of $r=e-v+2$, but to use this I need to find the number of edges first. So how do I find the number of edges in a graph if I know how many vertices there are and their degrees?

Comment: See [Handshaking Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) and the degree sum formula (naming of these varies among authors).

Comment: Note that the notion "regions a graph has" is meaningful only for planar graphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum of the vertex degree values is twice the number of edges, because each of the edges has been counted from both ends.

In your case $6$ vertices of degree $4$ mean there are $(6\times 4) / 2 = 12$ edges.

Comment: ...and without giving too much away, there is only one simple graph that has $6$ vertices all of degree $4$, and it corresponds to one of the regular polyhedra.